# large sparse matrix, svd with spark,python

Tags: apache-spark, svd

I want to analyze data on spark. I need svd matrix to achieve recommendation algorithm using python or scala if python doesn't work. But the data is large and sparse.

there are two columns in  the data. one is user name, the other one is item name.
If user and item are in one row, then that means the user like this item.
there are 700k items and 20k users. So it case memoryerror.

How to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you load the data under scipy [csr matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html).

It is much more efficient to store sparse matrices than using numpy.

Best.